# Can I negate nouns with negative words?

Tags: negation

“People in nowhere live on the other planets”.

It means people in everywhere don’t live on the other planets.

“People in nowhere can fly in the sky”.

It means people in everywhere can’t fly in the sky.

Do these sentences make sense?

Comment: No sense whatever! _Nowhere_ and _everywhere_ don't need _in_, but in any case the statements are illogical.

Comment: All your examples are simply nonsense.

Comment: _I got nobody's answer_ is grammatical and comprehensible, though not idiomatic. _I got nobody's care_ is grammatical, but it is not clear what it means, because "get X's care" is not an idiomatic expression. _I was under nobody's care_ is perfectly good, because "be under X's care" _is_ idiomatic.

Comment: @Colin Fine Thank you.

Comment: @ColinFine "My friend John received medical care from that pretty nurse, but I got nobody's care." I admit that it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Note also, @Gabriel, that _I got nobody's answer_ would have a slightly different meaning from _I got no answer_ or _I didn't get an answer_, because it is bringing the people (presumably, the people who might have given answer) into the scenario. It suggests that people had answers but weren't giving them, or you didn't hear them; whereas _I got no answer_ doesn't have that suggestion.

Comment: @Colin Fine Is that suggestion a special case in English?

Comment: @Gabriel. No, If you use a more specific negator than "no" or "none" (eg _nobody_, _nowhere_, _never_) youl are implicitly introducing its related concept (person, place, time) into the scenario. This won't necessarily alter the meaning, but it might.

Comment: @Colin Fine Thank you for sparing your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kate says, we don't use *in* with *everywhere* or *nowhere*.

Without that, your sentences are just about grammatical, but not idiomatic. With negative adverbs like that, it is more common to put them first, and invert the verb:

> Nowhere can people fly in the sky.

is perfectly good, (though not true unless you mean "fly under their own power").

> Nowhere do people live on other planets.

is grammatical, but doesn't make any sense. I think the pattern you are looking for would be

> People live nowhere on other planets.

which I don't think anybody is likely to say, but is grammatical. This makes  *nowhere on other planets* a single adverbial phrase with *on other planets* restricting *nowhere*. It doesn't make sense to have *nowhere* and *on other planets* as separate constituents, because they're both locative (denoting places) and contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

To “be nowhere” is not the same as to “be everywhere but not ____”. You cannot *be* “in nowhere.” Neither should you ever use “in” before nowhere OR everywhere. But if you’re trying to use logical analysis to approach grammatical rules, perhaps you should also consider the logical validity of your example statements.